# JavaScript sum function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sum, return

I have stacked in the sum of an array. The code is bellow

```
function User(name,email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.cartAmount = [];
        this.total = 0;
}
User.prototype = {
        constructor: User,

        addCart: function(mrp){
            this.cartAmount.push(mrp);
        },

        changeEmail: function(newmail){
            this.email = newmail;
        },

        showCart: function() {
            var cart = this.cartAmount.length >0 ? this.cartAmount.join("tk,") : "No product in the cart";
            return this.name+" has "+cart+" in his cart.";
        },

        intotal: function(){
            for(var n in this.cartAmount){
                this.total += this.cartAmount[n];
                return this.total;
            }
        }
    };
    athar= new User("Athar Jamil", "atharjamil@gmail.com");
    console.log(athar.name);
    athar.changeEmail("atharjamil@yahoo.com");
    console.log(athar.email);
    athar.addCart(20);
    athar.addCart(50);
    athar.addCart(80);
    console.log(athar.intotal());
```

It shows me only 20 as the result of the sum. What is the problem?

Comment: Return is perform early man!

Comment: How is this a Hot Network Question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're `return`ing too early, hence your `for` loop runs only once and returns the first item in the cart.

Try this instead:

```
 intotal: function(){
    for(var n in this.cartAmount){
        this.total += this.cartAmount[n];
    }

    return this.total;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Do not use `this.total` for that. If you call this method several times, your total will increase each time you call it. You should at least put a `this.total = 0` at the top of your method.

I personally would have written it like this instead :

```
intotal: function(){
    var out = 0;
    for(var n in this.cartAmount){
        out += this.cartAmount[n];
    }

    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) you can simplify that function a lot:

```
intotal: function() {
  return this.cartAmount.reduce((a, b)=> a + b)
}
```

From MDN:

> The **`reduce()`** method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

Here you pass an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to the `reduce` method, which takes two arguments: `a` and `b`, and returns sum of them.

Answer (score 4):

intotal function returning the first element of cartAmount array.
Place the return statement of intotal function outside of for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sum(){
 var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
 return args.reduce(function(pre,curr){
   if(!isNaN(curr)){
     return pre+curr;
   }
   else
   {
    throw Error("Non-Numeric arguments"+curr);
   }
},0)
}
    var result = sum(12,13,14); //pass any number of parameter to sum
    alert("Sum Is:"+result);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mnjs

First import sum function from mnjs package

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mnjs/browser/index.js"></script>
```

or

const { sum } = require('mnjs')

or

import { sum } from 'mnjs'

Then use sum function as follow:

```
const cartAmount = [1, 4, 2]

sum(cartAmount)   // returns 7
```

https://runkit.com/dr-montasir/mnjs-sum-function